# Reading all files in a path and checking on them java

Tags: java, filereader

I am reading all files in the paths which mentioned in the code

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public class folderReader {

        public static void main(String[] args) {


            //Extension > .wav files
            File folderWav = new File(
                    "/home/bassem/Desktop/LatestData3/Nemlar_RMC/nemlar_RMC");
            File[] listOfWavs = folderWav.listFiles();


            //Extension > .insent
            File folderInsent = new File(
                    "/home/bassem/Desktop/LatestData3/outputInsent");
            File[] listOfInsents = folderInsent.listFiles();


            //Extension > .ctl
            File folderCtl = new File("/home/bassem/Desktop/LatestData3/outputCtl");
            File[] listOfCtls = folderCtl.listFiles();



            for (File file : listOfWavs) {
                for (File file2 : listOfInsents) {
                    for (File file3 : listOfCtls) {
                        if (file.isFile() && file2.isFile() && file3.isFile()) {

                            if ((file.getName().substring(0,
                                    file.getName().length() - 4).equals(file3
                                    .getName().substring(0,
                                            file3.getName().length() - 4)))) {
                                if ((file2.getName().substring(0,
                                        file2.getName().length() - 7).equals(file3
                                        .getName().substring(0,
                                                file3.getName().length() - 4)))) {
                                    System.out.println(file3.getAbsolutePath());
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

After Reading all the files I am checking on their names with using substring to remove (.ctl - .insent - .wav) and if they are equaled I should do some stuff I am trying here to print path to check if the code is working and it prints nothing

I tried to use this and it worked well it printed them all.

```
    for (File file : listOfWavs) {
    for (File file2 : listOfInsents) {
        if (file.isFile() && file2.isFile()) {
            if ((file.getName().substring(0,
                    file.getName().length() - 4).equals(file2.getName()
                    .substring(0, file2.getName().length() - 7)))) {

                System.out.println(file2.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem only happens when i am checking on the 3 folders together when I run the code it does nothing just an empty console !

Comment: Oh god. Please use the NIO.2 API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html. This will most certainly solve whatever problem you have. This is Java 7.

Comment: @Tunaki I won't be able to apply .length() to remove some characters from each file's name I think there's nothing equivalent to this in Path class

Comment: There is [`Files.size`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#size-java.nio.file.Path-)... Really, use the latest API, they were specifically written to ease that burden.

Comment: @Tunaki Files.size() wouldn't achieve what I need because I need to apply the equality logic on the file's name which is in my case now "Path" so i can use .getFileName() but cant remove the last few letters in it to be able to compare

Comment: Sure you can. Read the tutorial about NIO.2 API I linked in my first comment. You will seriously make your code _a lot_ easier to read and understand. There is a reason this API was developed.

Answer (score 0):

```
String folder = "/home/bassem/Desktop/LatestData3/";

List<String> insents = readFolderBasenames(folder + "outputInsent", "insent");
List<String> wavs = readFolderBasenames(folder + "Nemlar_RMC/nemlar_RMC", "wav");
List<String> ctls = readFolderBasenames(folder + "outputCtl", "ctl");

insents.retainAll(wavs);
insents.retainAll(ctls);

for(String file : insents) {
    System.out.println(folder + file + ".insent");
}


private List<String> readFolderBasenames(String path, String extension) {
    File[] arr = new File(path).listFiles());
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].getName().substring(0, arr[i].getName().length() - extension.length() - 1);
    }
    return Arrays.asList(arr);
}
```

Comment: Please also explain how and why this might help

Comment: Much clearer what it does (no 3 nested for-loops + 3 nested if statements). Also much faster: O(n) instead of O(n^3)

Comment: @XsafasfaYadasd this line    `arr[i] = arr[i].getName().substring(0, arr[i].getName().length() - extension.length() - 1);`  causes an error >> **Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to File**